# Complex Analysis, Differentiability

Tags: complex-analysis

Working on this problem in complex analysis. I think I have the right approach, but it doesn't seem to be working out.

Suppose $f(z)=az^2+bz\bar{z}+c\bar{z}^2$ where $a, b, c$ are fixed copmlex numbers. Show $f(z)$ is differentiable iff $bz+2c\bar{z}=0$.

$f(z)$ can be rewritten as $(a+b+c)x^2+(b-a-c)y^2+i*2(a-c)xy$

So I know we have differentiability of $f(z)$ iff the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold (note both $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are continuous and differentiable). For the forward direction, if $f(z)$ is differentiable we have by the CR equations first that

$2(a+b+c)x=2(a-c)x$ which implies $b=-2c$.

Now if we consider $bz+2c\bar{z}=0$ or $x(b+2c)+iy(b-2c)=0$, we see that if $b=-2c$ the x term goes away, but the second does not. I cant seem to find my mistake, so any input would help.

Comment: If $b$ and $c$ are fixed how is $bz + 2c\bar z$ going to hold for *all* complex $z$?

Comment: @UmbertoP.: More precisely, it's differentiable at $z$ iff $bz+2c\bar z=0$ for that particular $z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have $b=-2c$ or $x=0$. Now what does the second CR equation tell you?

**EDIT**: For the second CR equation, I get that $(b-a-c)y = -2(a-c)y$, so $b=+2c$ or $y=0$. Thus, we get $b=c=0$ or $x=y=0$.

Comment: The second equation shows either $y=0$ or $2a+b=0$. So now I see the answer is obvious when we take $x=0$ and $y=0$ as the solutions, but how do we account for the other solutions involving $a, b, c$?

Comment: Check your algebra. I edited with a bit more.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing. In proving the reverse direction, we can assume that equation, and show that having this equation implies the Cauchy Riemann equations hold. However, having this equation does not necessarily imply both parts of real and imaginary parts of $bz+2c\bar{z}$ are identically zero. It could also be that they are opposites? So i'm not sure how they directly imply the CR equations as true.

Comment: @Leif: Au contraire: A complex number is $0$ iff both its real and imaginary parts *must* be $0$.

Answer (score 2):

A more abstract approach would be using another formulation of the Cauchy-Riemann equations. We have the following theorem:

> Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be open and $f: D \to \mathbb{C}$ be
>   real-differentiable in $D$. Then $f$ is holomorphic in $D$ if and only
>   if $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}(z_0) = 0$$ holds for all
>   $z_0 \in D$.

Now we have
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}(z) = bz + 2c\overline{z}$$ by the Wirtinger-calculus.

Comment: I personally love $\partial/\partial z$ and $\partial/\partial\bar z$, but I believe this is beyond the current level of the OP. But it's stronger than you're saying. The CR equations (and hence $\partial f/\partial\bar z = 0$) can hold at isolated points.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think that, too. But I wanted to add it nonetheless since it provides a quick proof. I've learned this in my first course on complex analysis at university. Thanks for the additional input!